# A productive alternative to UML

Tags: uml, notation

I find UML hard to create quickly.
I'd like to put my ideas more quickly, especially for small open sourced projects.
If it was big enough I'd bother with UML but the project is too small for this kind of thing.
I don't want yet another tool that will make me think "nehh I'll do it later".
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use a blog (WordPress is quick) or a mind map ([here](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Main_Page)'s one free on Sourceforge)

Comment: If you can figure out a productive way to use it in can. By that I mean that if you are disciplined in using it frequently, by the end of your project, you will have tons of notes about architecture, ideas for improvement, ideas for where to expand, and the beginnings of formal documentation.

It will take a little getting used to the workflow with one of these tools, but if you find UML to be too cumbersome, this is probably a valid alternative.

Answer (score 7):

UML is not a tool, it's a language.

If you want a tool that is quick and easy, I'd recommend a whiteboard. If you need a permanent copy of your design, take a photo of the whiteboard.

Comment: In my company we have whiteboards which can scan their selfs and print out a copy (sadly b/w). Im sure there are more modern products out there :)

Answer (score 7):

For me, UML somehow always seemed to complicate things more than help them. However, I found [yUML](http://yuml.me/diagram/class/draw2) to work perfectly for quick sketches just like the ones you mention.

Comment: yUML not allows you to make sequence diagrams.

Answer (score 2):

UML itself is a specification of a language that is intended to ease communication. It can be used differently, or for different purposes. Martin Fowler suggests some [Uml-modes](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/UmlMode.html). The main uses are the [blueprint](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/UmlAsBlueprint.html) the [Sketch](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/UmlAsSketch.html) and the [Language](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/UmlAsProgrammingLanguage.html) mode.

I favor to use the Sketch sice it gives you the freedom to use some diagram or not. Just as you like.

Answer (score 0):

I use Backpack from 37signals for many years. You can open free account there.
Here is the link http://www.backpackit.com/

Comment: It's not free.
We're talking about open source projects.

Comment: It is free! Free accounts are available at
https://signup.37signals.com/backpack/free/signup/new

Comment: @the_drow Its free but no free software, thats a difference. You asked for none of both.